# Syntax assistance for database package

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, package, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle 11G database.  We have a C# application that speaks to a PL/SQL package that sends a user an email if a number of criteria are met.  The example deals primarily with a PERSON table & an APPOINTMENT table.

Here is the logic we currently have:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE BODY email_send_pkg
IS 
PROCEDURE sp_email_reminder(p_HOURS IN NUMBER,
                                  p_message_cur IN OUT MessageCur)  
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN p_message_cur
     FOR 
SELECT a.person_id, 
       a.appoint_no,
       a.appoint_date_time,           
       p.name, 
       p.forename,
       p.surname,
       p.email_addre,
       l.location_name, 
       NVL(l.address1, ''), 
       NVL(l.address2, ''), 
       NVL(l.address3, '') 

  FROM appointment a,
       person p,
       location l
  WHERE a.appoint_date_time > SYSDATE   -- only send email for appointments in the future
  AND (sa.appoint_date_time - ((1/24) * p_HOURS)) < SYSDATE 
    AND a.cancel_date IS NULL -- only send email for appointment that have NOT been cancelled
    AND a.resched_date IS NULL -- only send email for appointment that have NOT been rescheduled
    AND p.person_id = a.person_id -- check correct record on PERSON table & APPOINTMENT table
    AND l.location_id = a.location_id -- check correct record on PERSON table & APPOINTMENT table
    AND email_addre IS NOT NULL -- only send email if email data exists for the person in question

    AND NOT EXISTS --avoid duplicate record
      ( SELECT *
          FROM email_message em
         WHERE em.appoint_no  = a.appoint_no
           AND em.message_type_id = 1  -- (type: example; appointment reminder)
      )
ORDER BY appoint_date_time ASC;
 END sp_email_reminder;
```

Assuming all the criteria are met, we then add the data to a table, which is polled later by the C# application to send out the emails.

I need to implement further logic to make a few more checks.  I'm reasonably unfamiliar with PL/SQL, and certainly it's syntax and need advice on adding more logic.

Currently, if a person shows up for their appointment and the system does NOT currently have their email stored, they are asked for it at reception.  Once it' added to the database (PERSON & PERSON_AUDIT tables updated) The C# application will poll, see the newly added email, and send an email to the person who is already sitting in the waiting room for that appointment.... Which is obviously a little silly & needless.

So, I need to insert some logic along the lines of: 
IF EMAIL_ADDRE is NO LONGER NULL on PERSON_AUDIT table on the APPOINT_DATE in question, then DONT send an email.

I'd also like to ensure emails are never sent on Saturdays or Sundays, or public holidays like Christmas for example.  (BUT still give them about 72 hours notice) I guess a solution for this would be to create a simple db table full of excluded dates, and check against that, but I've no idea howto actually implement that with my current knowledge of PL/SQL.

Any tips on syntax or comments on the current logic would be great!
Thanks.

Solution:    (thanks to Starfighter)

```
AND NOT EXISTS
    (  SELECT *
         FROM audituser.person_a pu
       WHERE pu.b_person_id = sa.person_id
      AND pu.b_email <> pu.a_email
        AND TRUNC(pu.a_last_upd_datetime) = TRUNC(sa.appoint_date)
        AND pu.a_email IS NOT NULL
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the end of your query:

```
and not exists (
  -- Avoid sending updates if person record changes on appointment date
  select 'X'
    from person_audit pa
   where a.person_id = pa.person_id
     -- Trunc is currently doing same day...
     -- this can be tweaked to look at range of minutes or hours
     and trunc(appoint_date_time)  trunc(last_upt_date_time)
     and pa.email_address is not null
)
```

This should effectively omit any records where the person record is updated (and the email address is not null) on (or after) the appointment date.

Comment: Awesome, I got this eventually, slightly different but your answer is great.  Thanks.  OP edited.